# Is there something like numpy.logspace in C++?

Tags: c++

As the title says, im looking for some function that generates log-spaces values, just like numpy.logspace does, but for python. And ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard library, however, you can easily write your own. Due to the different nature of C++ and Python, the function isn't going to be identical. I'd recommend using generator-style function object:

```
template<typename T>
class Logspace {
private:
    T curValue, base;

public:
    Logspace(T first, T base) : curValue(first), base(base) {}

    T operator()() {
        T retval = curValue;
        curValue *= base;
        return retval;
    }
};
```

Example usage (40 values with base of 2 starting with 1):

```
std::vector<double> vals;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vals), 40, Logspace<double>(1,2));
```

Example solution to comment:

```
std::vector<double> pyLogspace(double start, double stop, int num = 50, double base = 10) {
    double realStart = pow(base, start);
    double realBase = pow(base, (stop-start)/num);

    std::vector<double> retval;
    retval.reserve(num);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(retval), num, Logspace<double>(realStart,realBase));
    return retval;
}
```

Example implementation of `generate_while`

```
template<typename Value, typename OutputIt, typename Condition, typename Generator>
void generate_while(OutputIt output, Condition cond, Generator g) {
    Value val;
    while(cond(val = g())) {
        *output++ = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im rather C++ beginner, but this does "just" calculate the log of a number, right? What i am looking for is more something like a function, that taktes MinValue, MaxValue and the number of bins inbetween.

Comment: You can use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with this object. However, AFAIK there is no `std::generate_until` function, you would have to write your own.

Comment: Im sorry, but i don't get this to work. Could you held me a bit more? I would need eg. 40 logspaced bins in the range from 1 to 1e6

Comment: It is really easy to write one starting from this snippet, which would imitate the `numpy` one. Just use `start`, `stop`, `num`, `base` compute the step from `start`, `stop` and `num`. Also, you should note that the `first` meaning in current example is different than in `numpy`, I think it's wrong and should be `curValue = pow(base, first)`.

Comment: Sorry, but i just don't get it. I added both templates to my header, but i receive errors from "vals.back_inserter" and Logspace

Comment: @user2003965 Please post the exact error message (including the source, if possible). Also see edit, added template parameter to the Logspace instance creation.

Comment: @Erbureth Your code is wrong `std::back_inserter(vals)` this is how you should use back inserter.

Comment: Synatax error, a ')' is missing. Second "outputit" is not declared

Comment: @user2003965 I have edited the answer to provide better example. However your errors look like simple typos, please do provide your source code.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think Erbureth code is wrong, but is was really easy to make the right one from the snippet he provided. Below is the generator + usage example.

The `Logspace` accepts arguments like `numpy.linspace` and will generate the same sequence. It can go past it. But the 1st values are the same. It works as if the `endpoint` was set to `True`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath> 

//for generator
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

template<typename T = double>
class Logspace {
private:
    T curValue, base, step;

public:
    Logspace(T first, T last, int num, T base = 10.0) : curValue(first), base(base){
       step = (last - first)/(num-1);
    }

    T operator()() {
        T retval = pow(base, curValue);
        curValue += step;
        return retval;
    }
};



int main(){
 int num = 4;
 Logspace<> generator(2, 3, 4, 2);
 for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i) std::cout << generator() << '\n';

 //
 std::cout << "1 to million\n";
 double start = 1;
 double stop = 6;
 num = 40;
 std::vector<double> vals;
 std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vals), num, Logspace<>(start,stop,num));
 for(double num : vals) std::cout << num << '\n';

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `pow` is more expensive operation than multiplication.

Comment: @Erbureth Yes, but how would you want to calculate `2 ^ 2.33` with simple multiplication? I think your code is wrong because you use wrong step. Can your code actually reproduce the expected sequence? In `linspace` steps are not `1.0`. You can throw in `std::cout << "exponent: " << curValue << "\n";` after `pow`.

Comment: His `realBase` value represents `pow(base, step_size)`, which he correctly uses.  Think of it this way: To get to the next value from the current value to the next one in the sequence you can do `next = pow(base, log(curr, base) + step)` which can be expanded to `next = pow(base, log(curr, base)) * pow(base, step)` and with one more step you get `next = curr * pow(base, step)`.  In his code, `realValue = pow(base,step)`.

Comment: @GuyGreer His comments were targeted to the fact, that my implementation wasn't 1:1 copy of the `numpy.logspace` function. The `pyLogspace` function was added afterwards.