# How to write a fast code in C++ compared to numpy.logspace() function?

Tags: python, c++, numpy

This is the code in Python that generates log-spaces values at a very quick time:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.logspace(0,1,num=10000000))
```

My try to simulate its output in C++, is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
std::vector<double> logspace (const double &a, const double &b, const int &k)
{
    std::vector<double> logspace;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        logspace.push_back(pow(10, i * (b - a) / (k - 1)));
    }
    return logspace;
}
void logspace_print (std::vector<double> logspace)
{
    for (auto ls : logspace)
    {
        std::cout << ls << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
int main ()
{
    std::vector<double> my_ls = logspace(0, 1, 10000000);
    logspace_print(my_ls);
}
```

Waiver of floating-points arithmetic, using the function `pow(., .)` and a `for`-loop (and maybe lots of other reasons), makes my code as a naive one such as its run-time is hugely faint with respect to the Python's one. I saw recommendations at [Is there something like numpy.logspace in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429294/is-there-something-like-numpy-logspace-in-c) also. But, there is not mentionable significant difference. So, how can I modify my code or write a new one comparable with python's version?

Comment: You could always look at the source code of numpy?

Comment: Sure. Why not. But, as you can see its source also, there is a chain of functions related to each other that one should look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question! My answer has the different versions of the functions at the top. Below is only the benchmarking code. Use google-benchmark as the library.

- My intermediate result can also be found here: [1](http://quick-bench.com/Hs39BWQf5kr5Gjnv6zQkLXMrsDw) Quick-Bench.com is generally a great site.
- You don't say if you want to measure printing to stdout as part of your use-case or not. Printing is generally expensive. You avoid `std::endl`'s flush, which is good! Furthermore, printf might be faster than std::cout. Also take a look at fmtlib [2](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). It is fast and easy to use.
- Generally, the approach that Numpy uses is fastest. (Named `logspace_v3` in my version.) It consists of first running `linspace` and then taking to the power of 10 in-place.
- Still, I strongly feel that I am missing quite a bit here. With the appropriate flags (`-march=native -mtune=native`, and fast-math) vectorization should kick in. But I don't believe it does. Here is some Godbolt with vectorization (Line 590) [3](https://godbolt.org/z/S4U7He).
- What was fasted was getting rid of the `pow` call. Note that this accumulates floating point error and leads to inaccurate results.
- Minor: There is no benefit of passing doubles or ints by const-reference.

[image: Benchmark comparison generated by Quick-Bench.com]

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

std::vector<double> logspace(double a, double b, int k) {
  std::vector<double> logspace;
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    logspace.push_back(pow(10, i * (b - a) / (k - 1)));
  }
  return logspace;
}

// Pre-allocate the correct size using .reserve()
std::vector<double> logspace_v1(double a, double b, int k) {
  std::vector<double> logspace;
  logspace.reserve(k);
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    logspace.push_back(pow(10, i * (b - a) / (k - 1)));
  }
  return logspace;
}

/// Manually extract the constant factor.
std::vector<double> logspace_v2(double a, double b, int k) {
  std::vector<double> logspace;
  logspace.reserve(k);
  const auto exp_scale = (b - a) / (k - 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    logspace.push_back(pow(10, i * exp_scale));
  }
  return logspace;
}

/// Copy the impl behavior of numpy.linspace: First linspace then power.
std::vector<double> logspace_v3(double a, double b, int k) {
  /*
  y = linspace(start, stop, num=num, endpoint=endpoint, axis=axis)
  if dtype is None:
      return _nx.power(base, y)
  return _nx.power(base, y).astype(dtype, copy=False)
  */
  const auto exp_scale = (b - a) / (k - 1);
  std::vector<double> logspace;
  logspace.reserve(k);
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    logspace.push_back(i * exp_scale);
  }
  std::for_each(logspace.begin(), logspace.end(),
                [](double &x) { x = pow(10, x); });
  return logspace;
}

/// Improve on v3 by applying pow directly
std::vector<double> logspace_v4(double a, double b, int k) {
  const auto exp_scale = (b - a) / (k - 1);
  std::vector<double> logspace(k, 0.);
  std::generate(logspace.begin(), logspace.end(),
                [n = -1, exp_scale]() mutable {
                  n++;
                  return pow(10, n * exp_scale);
                });
  return logspace;
}

/// Use generate_n : First linspace then power.
std::vector<double> logspace_v5(double a, double b, int k) {
  const auto exp_scale = (b - a) / (k - 1);
  std::vector<double> logspace(k, 0.);
  std::iota(logspace.begin(), logspace.end(), 0);
  std::for_each(logspace.begin(), logspace.end(),
                [exp_scale](double &x) { x *= exp_scale; });
  std::for_each(logspace.begin(), logspace.end(),
                [](double &x) { x = pow(10, x); });
  return logspace;
}

std::vector<double> logspace_v6(double a, double b, int k) {
  const auto exp_scale = (b - a) / (k - 1);
  const auto factor = pow(10, exp_scale);
  std::vector<double> logspace;
  logspace.reserve(k);

  // val = pow(b, i * exp_scale);
  // = pow(pow(b, exp_scale), i);
  // = pow(f, i); with f := pow(b, exp_scale);
  // next = cur * f;
  // first = pow(b, a);

  double val = pow(10, a);
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    logspace.push_back(val);
    val *= factor;
  }
  return logspace;
}

template <std::vector<double> (*F)(double, double, int)>
static void LogspaceBench(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(F(0, 1, state.range(0)));
  }
}
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace)->Arg(1000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v1)->Arg(1000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v2)->Arg(1000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v3)->Arg(1000)->Arg(10000000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v4)->Arg(1000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v5)->Arg(1000);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(LogspaceBench, logspace_v6)->Arg(1000)->Arg(10000000);

class LogspaceTest
    : public testing::TestWithParam<
          std::function<std::vector<double>(double, double, int)>> {};

TEST_P(LogspaceTest, IsSame) {
  auto func = GetParam();
  const auto actual = func(0, 1., 1000);
  const auto expected = logspace(0., 1., 1000);
  // TODO: Buggy with (3, 70, 1000) and (0, 1, 1000)
  ASSERT_EQ(expected.size(), actual.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
    ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ(actual[i], expected[i]) << i;
  }
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(InstantiationName, LogspaceTest,
                         testing::Values(logspace, logspace_v1, logspace_v2,
                                         logspace_v3, logspace_v4, logspace_v5,
                                         logspace_v6));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
  ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Printf is only faster than cout when they're synchronized (which is true by default). You can use std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); to disable that.

Comment: "Printing is generally expensive." Printing to a file is expensive. Printing to a _terminal_ takes an eternity. That's why the Python and C++ are comparable performance I bet. Pipe the output to a file to be a better comparison of the languages themselves. Right now he's probably profiling the terminal.

Comment: I’ve not looked at the printing in my answer. Too long already.

Comment: @Unapiedra, I am enjoying from your nice answer (Moreover, thanks from recommending the Google-benchmark. It sounds great).

Comment: @Unapiedra & @Mooing Duck, I understand the really bad performance (and so effect) of printing in run-time (To be more precise, Python is using a kind of cunning trick to print. Indeed, it doesn't print all the output ;) ). Anyway, I have an idea about increasing the `for`-loop performance. Before trying, I want to study its theory: Is it a good way to partition the  interval `[0, 10000000]` into (for example) `[0, 1000] U [1000, 10000] U ... U [1000000, 10000000]` and apply the for loop on them?

Comment: By `for`-loop, I mean any method to full vector positions.

Comment: @epol no, that will almost certainly slow it down

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three obvious optimizations that can be easily made to the shown code.

1) Compile in C++17 mode to get guaranteed copy elision when returning from `logspace`.

2)

```
std::vector<double> logspace;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
```

Use `logspace.reserve()` to preallocate the vector, to avoid useless repeated reallocations, while this vector gets populated.

3)

```
void logspace_print (std::vector<double> logspace)
```

Passing by value here creates an entire duplicate copy of the vector, for no useful purpose whatsoever. Change this function so that it takes the `logspace` parameter by reference.

There's one possible micro-optimization that may or may not make any difference:

```
logspace.push_back(pow(10, i * (b - a) / (k - 1)));
```

The "(b-a)/(k-1)" part of this formula is constant and can be unrolled out of the loop. I would, though, expect the compiler to do it on its own, it's a fairly basic optimization.

Comment: I applied 2), 3) and your  micro-optimization recommendation (Unfortunately, I can not switch on c++17-compiler yet). But, the difference is less that 1 second (I used `time` command in Linux to compare the run-times).

Comment: I'd give a +1, except you've overlooked the performance of the terminal.